# Google Drive API for Objective-C with CocoaPods not linking GTMOAuth2 and

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to incorporate Google Drive API into my Objective-C app.  I'm using this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/intro).  I setup the quickstart example and that works fine.  For my app, I added the API using CocoaPods as directed.  When I run the app, I get linker errors not finding GTMOAuth2, GTMSessionFetcher and GoogleAPIClient.  Here is one example.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA/dntvfajcuzknsddygndaenxbqsii/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMOAuth2'

Under Target->Build settings -> other linker flags
-ObjC -l"GTMOAuth2" -l"GTMSessionFetcher" -l"GoogleAPIClient" -framework "Security" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -lz
```

for run path search paths, I have `@executable/Frameworks`

Can some provide info on how to probably setup Xcode so it finds GTMOAuth2, GTMSessionFetcher and GoogleAPIClient that are setup by the CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the installation process as discussed in [Install a Google SDK using CocoaPods](https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods) or in [Google APIs for iOS](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google) which gives the following steps in adding a Google SDK to your iOS app:

> CocoaPods is used to install and manage dependencies in existing Xcode projects.
>
> 1. Create an Xcode project, and save it to your local machine.
> 2. Create a file named `Podfile` in your project directory. This file defines your project's dependencies, and is commonly referred to as a Podspec.
> 3. Open `Podfile`, and add your dependencies.
> 4. Save the file.
> 5. Open a terminal and `cd` to the directory containing the Podfile.
> 6. Run the `pod install` command. This will install the SDKs specified in the Podspec, along with any dependencies they may have.
> 7. Open your app's `.xcworkspace` file to launch Xcode. Use this file for all development on your app.

Please also check the list of [CocoaPods published by Google](https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods#cocoapods_published_by_google).

Furthermore, you may want to continue the setup using the approaches to add the library to your project as discussed in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary) such as using [GTM OAuth2](https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2) or [Google Sign-In SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) and adding the framework to an Xcode project.

Lastly, to help you troubleshoot problems during installation, you may visit this [guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting#installing-cocoapods).